# Implementing \DeclareUnicodeCharacter in LuaLaTeX an XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode

In my code, I used to write

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{27E6}{\begin{description}} % ⟦
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{27E7}{\end{description}} % ⟧ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2022}{\item} %  •
```

which worked great with `pdflatex`. Moving to `lualatex` the command does not compile. Is there a way I can define my version of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacer` so that it still works?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd consider

```
⟦
•[Gnats] are small animals
•[Gnus] are big animals
⟧
```

as code obfuscation. Anyway, this works with all engines. However, for `pdflatex` it requires `utf8` passed to `inputenc` or `inputenx` (as opposed to `utf8x`).

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{⟦}{\begin{description}}
\newunicodechar{⟧}{\end{description}}
\newunicodechar{•}{\item}
```

If you want to reuse the declarations you already have, you could do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\newif\ifunicode
\ifxetex\unicodetrue\fi
\ifluatex\unicodetrue\fi

\ifunicode
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{newunicodechar}
  \newcommand{\DeclareUnicodeCharacter}[2]{%
    \begingroup\lccode`|=\string"#1\relax
    \lowercase{\endgroup\newunicodechar{|}}{#2}%
  }
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{27E6}{\begin{description}} % ⟦
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{27E7}{\end{description}} % ⟧ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2022}{\item} %  •

\begin{document}

Some text
⟦
•[Gnats] are small animals
•[Gnus] are big animals
⟧
and some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great. But, I have a hundred or so of these.

Comment: @YossiGil A hundred or so of what?

Comment: I have a hundred or so of these macros. So, it would require some manual work to convert \DeclareUnicodeCharacter to a simple \newunicodechar. But your final macro solved this.

Comment: I wonder why you consider this obfuscation? I use macros of this sort extensively, and it does help to remove clutter from the LaTeX code. It comes in very handy in making beamer applications. I have macros that convert control sequences to unicode, so typing is never an issue.