# Defining a replacement of a unicode character in lualatex

Tags: luatex, unicode

In the past I asked a question about a replacement character for a unicode character (FFFD) in case of and xelatex ([Defining a replacement of a unicode character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427270/defining-a-replacement-of-a-unicode-character)), this works nicely. Now I need it for lualatex as well  and found: [Implementing \DeclareUnicodeCharacter in LuaLaTeX an XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195458/implementing-declareunicodecharacter-in-lualatex-an-xelatex)

So I tried to implement it (note there is no document yet as it crashes beforehand):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\newif\ifunicode
\ifluatex\unicodetrue\fi

\ifunicode
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{newunicodechar}
  \newcommand{\DeclareUnicodeCharacter}[2]{%
    \begingroup\lccode`|=\string"#1\relax
    \lowercase{\endgroup\newunicodechar{|}}{#2}%
  }
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\def\ucr{\adjustbox{width=\CodeWidthChar,height=\CodeHeightChar}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\small ?}}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}

\ifunicode
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{\ucr}
\else
  % some other stuff
\fi

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

though this gives the error message:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
\newunicodechar #1#2->\if \relax \detokenize {#1}
                                                 \relax \nuc@emptyargerr \el...

l.23   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{\ucr}
```

Any solution?

EDIT, based on @DavidCarlisle (used edit because of readability):
I tried `\newunicode{?}{\ucr}` and get:

`! Undefined control sequence.
l.24   \newunicode
                {∩┐╜}{\ucr}`

(and with `\newunicode{\ucr}{?}`  in get

`! Undefined control sequence.
l.25   \newunicode
                {\ucr}{∩┐╜}`.)

Comment: you don't need to use any of those tests' just use egreg's `\newunicodechar` command it works in luatex or pdftex.  But your source should not have any U+FFFD characters in it so you shouldn't need to define that??

Comment: The document is a generated document and gets, unfortunately, those characters in it.  I tried to replace `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` with `\newunicode` and as first argument either `FFFD` or `�` but both failed.

Comment: `\newunicodechar{�}{?}`  should work in both systems. But better would be to fix your generation system, U+FFD means that the input was corrupted and the original information could not be reconstructed so some system  has given up and just replaced the original data by �

Comment: I think this suggestion does made some sense that for the the `FFFD` values I would directly write out `\ucr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like David Carlisle mentioned in a comment, `\newunicodechar` works for all engines. You use it like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\newif\ifunicode
\ifluatex\unicodetrue\fi

\ifunicode
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\def\ucr{X}

\newunicodechar{�}{\ucr}

\begin{document}
Hallo �.
\end{document}
```

The character U+FFFD is special through: LuaTeX uses it internally to mark invalid Unicode, so every time LuaTeX finds U+FFFD in your input, LuaTeX shows an error message. If you tell LuaTeX to continue, your document should still work.

This is a good example, why your source code should never contain characters like this.
If you still want to do this, you can use a Lua callback to replace the U+FFFD character before LuaTeX sees it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ifluatex
\usepackage{luacode}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\def\ucr{X}

\ifluatex
  \begin{luacode*}
    luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', function(buf)
      return buf:gsub(string.utfcharacter(0xFFFD), [[\ucr ]])
    end, 'replace U+FFFD')
  \end{luacode*}
\else
  \newunicodechar{�}{\ucr}
\fi

\begin{document}
Hallo �.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your first example (cut and paste), but still the same problem. With example 2 I get that it tries to install `luacode.sty` but cannot find it.

Comment: ah yes sorry i did know luatex special cases that really, but forgot when making the comment under the question

Comment: In respect to my previous comment,  I was referring here to MikTeX, but it looks like my MikTeX installation  has some problems at the moment (strange as I didn't change anything, as one always says ;-) ).  Switching to TexLive 2018 on Cygwin. The second example runs with the simle definition of `\ucr` to X, but with the requested definition I get: `! Undefined control sequence.
\ucr ->\adjustbox
                  {width=\CodeWidthChar ,height=\CodeHeightChar }{\stackinse...

l.27 Hallo \ucr
              .
`.

Comment: Regarding my last  comment this is my mistake. I forgot to include some  packages and defines etc. Sorry. I tested now with pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex and all 3 worked (MikTex and TexLive). (MikTeX mysteriously started to work again).